# SQL Server stored procedure to JSON error

Tags: sql-server, json, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write the following stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertAudit]
    (@val1 VARCHAR(100),
     @val2 VARCHAR(200))
AS
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @return_value varchar(max)
    /************************************/
    /*            The Query             */
    /************************************/
    EXEC [dbo].[SerializeJSON] 
    'INSERT INTO tLogin (EMP, LoginInTime) 
     VALUES (@val1, @val2)'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    /************************************/
    /*      Get Error results back      */
    /************************************/
    EXEC [dbo].[SerializeJSON] 
    'SELECT ERROR_NUMBER()  AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY()    AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE()       AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE()   AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE()        AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE()     AS ErrorMessage'
END CATCH
```

The `SerializeJSON` stored procedure (found [here](https://nyquist212.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/tsql-to-json-2/)) is this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SerializeJSON] 
    (@ParameterSQL AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XMLString VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @XML XML
    DECLARE @Paramlist NVARCHAR(1000)

    SET @Paramlist = N'@XML XML OUTPUT'
    SET @SQL = 'WITH PrepareTable (XMLString)'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AS('
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @ParameterSQL + 'FOR XML RAW,TYPE,ELEMENTS'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ')'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT @XML=[XMLString]FROM[PrepareTable]'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        , @Paramlist
        , @XML = @XML OUTPUT

    SET @XMLString = CAST(@XML AS VARCHAR(MAX))

    DECLARE @JSON VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Row VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @RowStart INT
    DECLARE @RowEnd INT
    DECLARE @FieldStart INT
    DECLARE @FieldEnd INT
    DECLARE @KEY VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @StartRoot VARCHAR(100);

    SET @StartRoot = '<row>'

    DECLARE @EndRoot VARCHAR(100);

    SET @EndRoot = '</row>'

    DECLARE @StartField VARCHAR(100);

    SET @StartField = '<'

    DECLARE @EndField VARCHAR(100);

    SET @EndField = '>'
    SET @RowStart = CharIndex(@StartRoot, @XMLString, 0)
    SET @JSON = ''

    WHILE @RowStart > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @RowStart = @RowStart + Len(@StartRoot)
        SET @RowEnd = CharIndex(@EndRoot, @XMLString, @RowStart)
        SET @Row = SubString(@XMLString, @RowStart, @RowEnd - @RowStart)
        SET @JSON = @JSON + '{'
        -- for each row
        SET @FieldStart = CharIndex(@StartField, @Row, 0)

        WHILE @FieldStart > 0
        BEGIN
            -- parse node key
            SET @FieldStart = @FieldStart + Len(@StartField)
            SET @FieldEnd = CharIndex(@EndField, @Row, @FieldStart)
            SET @KEY = SubString(@Row, @FieldStart, @FieldEnd - @FieldStart)
            SET @JSON = @JSON + '"' + @KEY + '":'
            -- parse node value
            SET @FieldStart = @FieldEnd + 1
            SET @FieldEnd = CharIndex('</', @Row, @FieldStart)
            SET @Value = SubString(@Row, @FieldStart, @FieldEnd - @FieldStart)
            SET @JSON = @JSON + '"' + @Value + '",'
            SET @FieldStart = @FieldStart + Len(@StartField)
            SET @FieldEnd = CharIndex(@EndField, @Row, @FieldStart)
            SET @FieldStart = CharIndex(@StartField, @Row, @FieldEnd)
        END

        IF LEN(@JSON) > 0
            SET @JSON = SubString(@JSON, 0, LEN(@JSON))
        SET @JSON = @JSON + '},'
        --/ for each row
        SET @RowStart = CharIndex(@StartRoot, @XMLString, @RowEnd)
    END

    IF LEN(@JSON) > 0
        SET @JSON = SubString(@JSON, 0, LEN(@JSON))
    SET @JSON = '[' + @JSON + ']'

    SELECT @JSON
END
```

When I execute the `spInsertAudit` stored procedure, I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.

So it did write to that table but for some reason it's not returning the JSON and having that error above....

Comment: The error is descriptive.  What exactly is confusing you about it?

Comment: @SamAxe Mainly why its coming up as that since its seems it works for the guy who posted it on that website I linked to.

Comment: You need to embed a space before the word `FOR` in the `FOR XML OUTPUT` declaration, so the word FOR is separated from the @ParameterSQL value.

Comment: @LaughingVergil that seems to have worked but now I am getting the error of **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.** which does not make any since either.

Comment: Try PRINTing the @SQL variable inside the SerializeJSON stored procedure. My bet is that you will see that the string contains this string: `VALUES (@val1, @val2)`. Ask yourself - what inside this stored procedure knows the values of the @val1 and @val2 variables that are not defined inside this stored procedure? How am I passing those values in?  Also look for simple concatenation created errors like the one corrected above.